Send Systemd Logs to GCP from Fluent-Bit Only Using a Service Account?
I have fluent-bit running on a GCP VM and sending systemd logs to files.
But I need to send these logs to GCP Logging.
Is there any way to avoid having to use a .JSON file for credentials? That is not a good practice. I want to use the VM's Service Account without having to manage .JSON keys.
Is this possible? I tried to use service_account_email per the documentation but the config was rejected on start.
I know about google-cloud-ops-agent and I want to avoid that at all costs based on problems we've had using Google-written utilities [cough, cough]
Thanks.
